# I am trying to write a For Loop in Python to identify types of sales for use with a 'sales report'

Tags: python

UPDATED - 4.13.22

I am new to programming python and am trying to create a program using For Loops that will go through a data frame by rows to identify different types of 'group sales' made up by different combinations of product sales and posting the results in a 'Result' column.

I was told in previous comments to print the df and paste it:

```
Date  LFMIX SALE  LCSIX SALE  LOTIX SALE  LSPIX SALE  LEQIX SALE  \
0   0.0         0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
1   0.0         0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
2   0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
3   0.0     25000.0     25000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
4   0.0     30000.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
5   0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0     30000.0   
6   0.0         0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0     30000.0   
7   0.0     25000.0     25000.0         0.0         0.0     25000.0   

   AUM LFMIX  AUM LCSIX  AUM LOTIX  AUM LSPIX  AUM LEQIX  \
0   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
1   500000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
2        0.0   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
3        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
4        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   200000.0   
5        0.0   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
6   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
7        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   

   is the sale = 10% of pairing fund AUM  LFMIX  LCSIX  LOTIX  LSPIX  LEQIX  \
0                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
1                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
2                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
3                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
4                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   
5                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   
6                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   
7                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   

  Expected_Result Result  
0             DP1         
1               0         
2             DP2         
3             DP3         
4             TT1         
5             TT2         
6             TT3         
7             TT4
```

my Python code to sort just the 1st row:

```
for row in range(len(df)):                                                                       
 if (df["LCSIX"][row] >= (df["AUM LFMIX"][row] * .1)): df["Result"][row] = "DP1"
```

and the results:

```
   Date  LFMIX SALE  LCSIX SALE  LOTIX SALE  LSPIX SALE  LEQIX SALE  \
0   0.0         0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
1   0.0         0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
2   0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
3   0.0     25000.0     25000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
4   0.0     30000.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
5   0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0         0.0     30000.0   
6   0.0         0.0     30000.0         0.0         0.0     30000.0   
7   0.0     25000.0     25000.0         0.0         0.0     25000.0   

   AUM LFMIX  AUM LCSIX  AUM LOTIX  AUM LSPIX  AUM LEQIX  \
0   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
1   500000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
2        0.0   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
3        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
4        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   200000.0   
5        0.0   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
6   200000.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   
7        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0   

   is the sale = 10% of pairing fund AUM  LFMIX  LCSIX  LOTIX  LSPIX  LEQIX  \
0                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
1                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
2                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
3                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   
4                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   
5                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   
6                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   
7                                    0.0      1      1    0.0    0.0    1.0   

  Expected_Result Result  
0             DP1         
1               0         
2             DP2    DP1  
3             DP3    DP1  
4             TT1    DP1  
5             TT2    DP1  
6             TT3         
7             TT4    DP1
```

As you can see, the code fail to identify row[0] as a DP1 and misidentifies other rows.

I am planning on coding 'For Loops' that will identify 17 different types of group sales, this is simply the 1st group I am trying to identify...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suggest you include necessary information in your question instead of posting pictures of it.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stack overflow :) Please see the guide to [ask], and check out the documentation on [formatting](/help/formatting). It's really important to format your code blocks, since in python, whitespace can totally change the meaning of a program! Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question;](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) instead, post data as code blocks. You can copy and paste the result of `print(df)` rather than taking a screenshot.

Comment: It is never a good idea to do things row-by-row with a pandas DataFrame.  What you're doing can be done in bulk.

Comment: this isn't an answer to your whole question, but you can't modify values in pandas with chained assignment, such as `df[colname][rowindex] = value`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/3888719) for more info.

Comment: In row 0, LCSIX is 1, and AUM_LFMIX is 20,000.  In the universe I know, I don't expect 1 to be greater than or equal to 10% of 20,000.  Did you mean to use "LCSIX_SALE"?  That's not what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

When you're working with pandas, you need to think in terms of doing things with whole columns, NOT row by row, which is hopelessly slow in pandas.  If you need to go row by row, then do all of that before you convert to pandas.

In this case, you need to set the "result" column for all rows where your condition is met.  This does that in one line:

```
df["result"][df["LCIX"] >= df["AUM_LFMIX"]*0.1] = "DP1"
```

So, we select the column as "result", and we select the rows where the relation is true.  Simple.  ;)

Comment: Hi Tim, I tweaked a few things and got your code to work so thanks!